# Transaction no confirmed and JUnit test assert fail

Tags: web3j

I have some JUnit test that assert some values returned from the blockchain deployed smart-contract. But the assert return me a error because the assertEqual call is done when the transaction has not been validated yet.

In Web3j 4.0.6 and a Quorum 2.2.3 version envyroment is ther a wey to make callbacks?

Im using the generated Web3j wrapper, the web3j quorum version is the following 4.0.6

Comment: can you provide more infos, are you using the smartcontract-wrappers to send the transaction? which java version? can you wait for events and then call the assertEqual() ?

Comment: I edit the question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you if you are stuck here, It is not the solution but you can do something like this. (worked for me with web3 "idk about Quorum")

For example if you have a **transfer(..)** function to send tokens in your smartcontract, then write another function **balanceOf(...)** to get the balance

And in your Unit-Test, send a transfer-transaction and then wait with a simple loop for about 10 second, and then call the method **balanceOf(..)** from your wrapper

I did something like this:

in my serviceClass i implemented a getBalance() method (same for transfer)

```
public int getBalanceOf(...) {
    TokenContract tokenContract = new TokenContract(<contract-address>, <web3j/quorum>, <credentials>, ....);
    return tokenContract.balanceOf(...);
}
```

In my Unit-Test class

```
@Test
void testTransferTokenContract() { 
    MyService service = new MyService();
    service.transfer(100,.....);
    ..wait about 10 seconds ..
    assertEquals(100, service.getBalanceOf(....));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So nowadays Web3j doesn't have promise to check when a transaction is confirmed. We have to manage this manually?

Comment: There is a transaction manager in web3j but (for me it was not very well documented and i couldn't find a lot of examples). Java has an awesome thing called CompletableFuture<..> , and with web3j it will look something like this CompletableFuture<TransactionReceipt> ... maybe this will be usefull for you